# Python script hang when uploading a file with selenium phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I need to upload an image using selenium and phantomjs, but the input field is generated only when i click an "upload file" button that pops up an "upload file" window on firefox.

I have this piece of code that is clicking on the "upload file" button to generate the html input field and then send the path to the image to it.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_button").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_input_field").send_keys(img_path)
```

Using firefox webdriver it is working fine but when using phantomjs webdriver the script hang when calling `send_keys()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this bug is coming from the PhantomJS driver itself, I just switched to headless chrome driver and it's working fine now.